# How to show login page first if anyone is trying to access my JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, authentication, url-routing

I am working on Spring MVC controller project. I have made a JSP page which is my simple UI -

So if I hit this url - `http://localhost:8080/testweb/testOperation` I can see my JSP page and everything is working fine. Below is the code for that which I added in my controller -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "testOperation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, String> zookOperation() {
    final Map<String, String> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    return model;
}
```

Now I am trying to add a login authentication to this. I am thinking if anyone who is trying to access this url `http://localhost:8080/testweb/testOperation` has to login first and then if it gets authenticated then only show the actual content of `testOperation` jsp page.

I already have created `login.jsp` page but how do I redirect to `login.jsp` page whenever somebody is trying to access this url `http://localhost:8080/testweb/testOperation` and then after authentication, I should show the actual content of `testOperation` jsp page.

Below is the code for `login.jsp` page

```
@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, String> login() {
    final Map<String, String> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    return model;
}
```

Is this possible to do so anyhow? If yes, any example will be of great help to me. Thanks.

I already have the authentication logic with me.

**Note:-** I want to do this login authentication only for this `testOperation` jsp page. For other jsp page which I have, I don't want to do that.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But my only intent was to encourage you to do some Google search before posting the question. I am really sorry but no wrong intents.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

Add security through your container using the standard Java API:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncby/index.html

Use Spring security and enable authentication to the pages you want to protect.
Samples: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/

Use Apache Shiro: https://shiro.apache.org/tutorial.html

I would usually go with using Spring Security and configure it through the xml config.

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.xml`, set the  to be `login.jsp`. Then people will be redirected there first. You should also check in `testOperation` that the person has logged in. So you need to save that login info somewhere for the controller to be able to check (example session variable). This will not provide the level of security talked about above for Spring Security, but it sounds like you want something that is easy and simple.

Comment: Sounds good. But is there any way I can redirect to login.jsp only for `testOperation` page not for all the jsp's?

Comment: Then I'd suggest that in testOperation, you check "userLoggedIn" (or some such thing" and if false, then `response.redirect("login.jsp");`

Comment: So, did that work? If so, mark as the correct solution so that others know what the solution is.

Answer (score 0):

In your jsp page.
add this validation at the start of  body tag of your jsp page.

```
if(session.getAttribute("username")==null){
            response.sendRedirect("redirect:http://localhost:8080/Login/LoginPage");
        }
```